# Json string parser using C

Tags: c, json

I was referring a site called "joys of programming" for JSON Parser in C. The site seems down and I am not able to get information regarding JSON parser. It would be great if some one can guide me. I want to know how to create a JSON Array.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make you own json parser, you have to look at the [language grammar](http://www.json.org/fatfree.html), which is probably [LL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). Writing such a LL parser is almost trivial and kind of funny, use a [regex library](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%20regex%20library) to save a precious time.

If you're looking for a library to deal with Json data, [here](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) is the second result [Google](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=json%20c%20library) gave me.

Comment: I have used Jansson library and can vote for it. readable source code if needed (i modified it a bit for my needs), good documentation, easy licencing and its maintainable (frequent releases).

Answer (score 1):

I found several lib could do this work.
Jsoncpp, JsonValue, cppCMS, JsonSpirit and Jansson. The jsonvalue is the easiest one. It just contains a pair of .h file and .cpp file.